# Selection of terms in Geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

How one can decide whether to take the terms as

1. $a, ar, ar^2$,

or

2. $a/r, a, ar$

for questions on geometric progression? Questions like :
If the sum of the first three terms in a GP is 26 and their product is 216. find the numbers.
in this case, I solved it with {1} but was not able to get the answer unless I used the {2} method.
thank you for the answers in advance!

Comment: When you say "solve" do you mean "**attempted** to solve"? Exactly what happened? Either way of starting should work.

Comment: To show the formulas more clearly in your working, see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation